# If $\int_0^T F(x_n(t)) dt- \int_0^T x_n^2(t) dt \to c$, how to prove that $\int_0^T F(x_n(t)) dt$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $T>0$ and $F$ be a real function. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of Lipschtizian functions over $[0, T]$ such that
$$\int_0^T F(x_n(t)) dt- \int_0^T x_n^2(t) dt \to c\quad\mbox{ as } n\to +\infty,$$
with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: it is true that $\int_0^T F(x_n(t)) dt\le M$, for a suitable constant $M>0$. About me the answer is yes since we have the convergence to $c$, but I don't know how to formally prove it.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is positive, if you have the additional assumption that $(x_n)_n$ is bounded. Then
$$\left|\int_0^T F(x_n(t))dt\right|\leq \left|\int_0^T F(x_n(t))-x_n^2(t)dt\right|+ \left|\int_0^T x_n^2(t)dt\right|,$$

where the first term on the right hand side is bounded because of the convergence and the second term because $x_n$ is bounded and $[0,T]$ is compact. For a counterexample just take $x_n(t)=nt$ and $F$ the identity, then the statement is false.